# Imagepath like /images/john works but on another server not

Tags: php, image, apache, url, path

I made a transfer of a CMS from one server to another. On the new server an image was not found. I looked in the HTML code and saw

```
<img src="/images/john" alt="john" />
```

The picture had no extension like `*.jpg`. But why did it work on the old server? It is the same code, same database and same htaccess file. Even Internet Explorer can find the picture.

Is an Apache or PHP configuration responsible for that behavior? I only want to find out why.

Comment: probably a missing rewrite or configuration of mime

Comment: You mean a missing rewrite in htaccess? With Mime you mean the mime type? There is no mime type because it is only a `img src`.

Comment: yes a missing rewrite probably the url `/images/john` may actually be rewritten or redirected to `/images/john.jpg` if or `/images/*` to `/images/$1.jpg` or probably it will be redirected in fact to a script that will process the request that will retrieve the data on the database server

Comment: The scripts are the same - so it should work on both. In the root folder there is no active htaccess file (only one with underscore _.htaccess). Hmm, I corrected the path and it works for this image.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that MultiViews is enabled on the old server but not on the new one? MultiViews is an Apache feature that lets you query for files without including the extension (so `images/john` might return the file at `images/john.jpg`). It is intended (as far as I'm aware) to allow you to have multiple versions of the same page, with the ultimate version picked depending on the user's locale; a browser requesting `index` from Spain might get `index.es.php` while in Japan it might get `index.jp.php`. I've never used this feature myself, so I don't know if that's the correct usage to serve locale-dependent pages, but I do know that MultiViews has the side effect of serving `index.php` in response to `index`.

Note that MultiViews is controlled by the `Options` directive, and it is the only such option that is not included in `All`. So to get all options including MultiViews, you would need `Options All MultiViews` in your `.htaccess` file. This may or may not enable MultiViews depending on the `Allow Override` directive in Apache's configuration for your directory; if you're on shared hosting there's nothing you can do but complain (although they tend to allow all `.htaccess` overrides to avoid such complaints).